# Relation Between iis worker process memory usage and disposing objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, iis

We are fetching a huge load of data from Sql Server by Entity Framework through code below

```
    using (var db=new Entities())
    {
        var list = db.spGetRecs().ToList();

       ///rest of the codes
    }
```

number of records is approximately 4 millions,and afterward iis gets so heavy and it's memory usage reaches to around `690 mb` and worker process does not release memory at all.
you can simply think of situation that multiple users use such amount of memory and then of course `out of memory exception` would occur.

I am gonna bring up three questions here:

1.Firstly,why iis worker process does not release memory?

2.Secondly,How can we force iis worker process releasing memory after we are done with data?

3.Thirdly,why despite i disposed all of objects that are related to this huge data,it didn't has any effect on `iis` memory usage?! then what is the point of disposing objects when it has nothing to do with windows process ?!

I didn't write whole lines of code because i didn't want to complicate the question and distract you from possible challenging concepts behind this question.

By the way, after i called garbage collector GC.Collect() it released around 20Mb from iis worker process.

Comment: The question to yourself is that how you did dispose all objects, as it does not seem that you had done it right. There are tons of good tools (memory profilers) and articles on how to analyze out of memory exceptions, but I don't think you really utilized all of them.

Comment: Do you need million records in memory at once, can you apply any `.Where(..)` calls? Also could you do the work you are trying to do without the `ToList()`, instead doing your work in a foreach so you don't need the entire list in memory at the same time? Also are you editing these objects and saving them back to the database, if you are doing a read only operation there are tweaks to your EntityFramework call you can do to make it use less memory.

Comment: Yes i need all of them...also its not matter of filtering...my question is a bit conceptual .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a big misunderstanding about disposing object and releasing memory.

When it comes to memory management theory regarding iis worker process we can think of it as following scenario,when a request is issued to iis,it needs a block of memory to store our request (threads) objects,Os allocates this memory blocks to iis worker process and when we are creating and filling objects in fact we are filling this blocks of memory,when we dispose our objects,In fact we are cleaning this blocks from our objects,we are responsible for data we put inside these blocks,not for the memory blocks itself.

It is operation system responsibility to manage it,when we dispose objects,this block is empty but Os does not retake it from worker process because it will be filled by another requests(threads) unless there is `shortage of RAM`,In this situation Os retakes amount of blocks that is not occupied by any live object,For Example when we execute a heavy query from sql it needs memory to execute,then ram shortage will be provided from iis worker process unoccupied blocks.

Of course the scenario you red above is just my understanding,But i would be happy to read your point of view.

Answer (score 2):

A process can still report a high allocation of RAM even when the objects that resulted in that memory allocation have been disposed. The memory may be still considered reserved but not committed, though honestly diving into the depths of how garbage collection works through releasing dead objects isn't something I've really needed to worry about except when tracking down unexplained growing memory use.

The first step should always be minimizing your memory footprint to accommodate concurrent requests.  For large requests you should consider implementing a request Queue with a background process that ensures that these requests are handled in a manner that a limited # of concurrent requests are processed at any one given time, or using resources on a different server so-as not to impact the responsiveness of the web-server.

Minimizing memory footprint size tips:

1. Use bounded contexts that contain lightweight entity definitions for the bare minimum fields your process needs. For instance if an entity normally contains 50+ columns where some of those fields are large strings, binary data, etc. that you don't need, having a bounded context with an entity definition that only refers to the 10 columns you need will save memory.
2. Take reasonable bites of the data. Utilize paging to only retrieve a manageable subset of data at any one time. I.e. 1000 records at a time. Leverage `Skip` and `Take` along with an `OrderBy` clause then look at the # of records returned to assess whether there are further pages to retrieve. (Rather than relying on a potentially expensive `Count` query.)

Background processes are a better solution for heavy querying/processing. If they can be run against a read-only replica rather than the main database, even better. Your web servers can receive a request with a given set of parameters, and instead of kicking off expensive queries that will starve the server, they can simply create a record in a processing Queue table to signal a background process to pick up that record and process it. That background process can be running on a completely different server or server farm. If the user is waiting for a result the web server can poll periodically for a status update from the background worker and display a result from the processing Queue table or related result table once the processing is completed. Queues can be serviced by several workers provided you have a synchronizing context to coordinate them and dole out work to avoid multiple workers from picking up the same job.

Edit: 
When it comes to garbage collection you are concerned because the process (garbage collector) is keeping the memory committed. You're expecting that if the code in question needs to allocated 1GB of ram, after a dispose or even a GC.Collect() the memory usage would drop by 1GB. It doesn't. The memory will still show up as committed to the process, but it is still available for that process' code. You can test this by running a huge query and letting the resulting entities/data expire. For example I had a recent test data set from another SO question where I populated 3M rows of data. With my system under a fair bit of load I tried reading all 3M rows into memory using:

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var test = context.Messages.ToList();
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

This churned along for a while and then crapped out with an out of memory exception at about 1.7GB according to the process monitor.   So I altered this to:

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var test = context.Messages.Take(1000000).ToList();
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

This completed using ~500MB of RAM.. So I had it execute 4 times in succession:

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var test = context.Messages.Take(1000000).ToList();
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var test = context.Messages.Take(1000000).ToList();
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var test = context.Messages.Take(1000000).ToList();
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var test = context.Messages.Take(1000000).ToList();
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

Now, if the initial 1M were "leaking", then my application process would have run out of memory. Except it didn't. The first climbed to ~500MB, the second climbed from there to ~1.1GB The third went to 1.6GB. The next started to climb, then saw-toothed down to ~1GB and continued climbing back to ~1.5GB. Every subsequent read sawtoothed down to remain somewhere between 1.4 and 1.5GB. I repeated with 6, 10 reads. At times it saw-toothed down to as low as 200MB, other times barely anything. No out of Memory exception or performance degradation with swaps to disc. Calling GC.Collect() did not visibly release the memory, even if called repeatedly or after each `using` block. The memory is "released" and reused with each subsequent call. Performance of each run or additional read block was consistent.

When running multiple instances of the test in parallel you can start to see performance degradation as each run can be seen allocating as much memory as it can up to the limit. The combined RAM demanded exceeds the free memory on the system so each takes turns spooling it's memory block to disc. The result is a significant performance drop with just 2 or 3 of these tests running in parallel (different VS instances) but still, no out of memory exceptions.

Comment: thank you @Steve,i appreciate the time that you have allocated on this topic,But it is still unclear and a bit vague that how a process is related to it's objects and why process does not commit allocated memory blocks while their objects are dead.

Comment: I've added an edit above with test observations around loading large volumes of data from a DbContext and the behavior of the garbage collection / disposal. The visible committed RAM usage of the process does not sawtooth immediately down, even when using a deliberate Collect, however the RAM is available for the process to use regardless of how many iterations / blocks it is loading over time.

Answer (score 0):

When an application starts and allocate memory, usually the OS system manages the memory and if another application needs an extra memory, it releases the memory. the real example like an expanse land that each application make a home in a specific space and when it's destroyed home, the land remains and don't destroy. So if the new application needs an extra memory, OS provides it with dispose of memory from the idle application.